# Using multiple JQuery UI tooltips on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using [JQuery UI's tooltips](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for a page using dynamic elements. It works perfectly on a single element, however when I attempt to add multiple tooltips the last tooltip defined seems to overwrite the existing items.

e.g.

```
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: ".testItem1",
    items: ".testItem1",
    content: "1"
});

$("body").tooltip({
    selector: ".testItem2",
    items: ".testItem2",
    content: "2"
});
```

In this case the second tooltip seems to overwrite the first.

Example (only the second items tooltip will work): https://jsfiddle.net/wce547w7/

Is there an alternative way to add tooltips to dynamic elements? Or can I use a property of some type to allow additional tooltips?

Edit: The dynamic elements are added outside of my control, so I cannot add the tooltip at the same time as creating the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use many tooltips?

```
// Add elements
var count = 0;
$(".addItem").on("click", function(){
    count++;
    $("body").append('<div class="testItem">Test ' + count + '</div>');
})

// Add tooltips
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: ".testItem",
    items: ".testItem",
    content: function() {return $(this).html();}

});
```

Comment: The example was just to show the effect, in the actual problem the tooltip isn't just the index of the element.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'll swap the html out for a data attribute and give it a try.

Comment: Works perfectly, I didn't even think about doing it that way. Thanks :)